# TRIPLE DES encryption/decryption using php

Tags: php, encryption, cryptography, tripledes

I have this TRIPLE DES ENCRYPTION CODE IN PHP

```
    $encryption_key = "CE51E06875F7D964";
    $data='tokenNo=test&securityCode=111' ;
    echo $desEncryptedData = encryptText_3des($data, $encryption_key);//outputs 3des encrypted data

function encryptText_3des($plainText, $key) {
    $key = hash("md5", $key, TRUE); 
    for ($x=0;$x<8;$x++) {
        $key = $key.substr($key, $x, 1);
    }
    $padded = pkcs5_pad($plainText,
        mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_3DES, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC));
    $encrypted = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_3DES, $key, $padded, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC));
    return $encrypted;
}
 function pkcs5_pad ($text, $blocksize)   
{
    $pad = $blocksize - (strlen($text) % $blocksize);
    return $text . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
}
```

Im able to encrypt the data as `xcFEvIdLXc2fjhG1i4iPOQu5L6ahxwZVucDOPqeMM2E=`

Now I have the key,will I able to decrypt this data to plain text format?

I tried it this way

```
            $encryption_key = "CE51E06875F7D964";
        $data='xcFEvIdLXc2fjhG1i4iPOQu5L6ahxwZVucDOPqeMM2E=' ; //encrypted data
        echo $desEncryptedData = encryptText_3des($data, $encryption_key);//outputs 3des encrypted data

    function encryptText_3des($plainText, $key) {
        $key = hash("md5", $key, TRUE); 
        for ($x=0;$x<8;$x++) {
            $key = $key.substr($key, $x, 1);
        }
        $padded = pkcs5_unpad($plainText,
            mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_3DES, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC));
        $encrypted = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_3DES, $key, $padded, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC));
        return $encrypted;
    }

    function pkcs5_unpad($text)   

    {
        $pad = ord($text{strlen($text)-1});
        if ($pad > strlen($text)) return false;
        if (strspn($text, chr($pad), strlen($text) - $pad) != $pad) return false;
        return substr($text, 0, -1 * $pad);
    }
```

But I couldnt do it.IS what I am doing is wrong?Please suggest me a way to decrypt this?Is the encryption key itself is used to decrypt the data in triple DES?Please help

Comment: Encrypting this kind of data (cookies or response parameters) is notoriously difficult to get right. CBC mode exposes a trivial padding oracle vulnerability. Replay attacks are even simpler. Key derivation is really dubious in this case as well.

Comment: It is best not to use PHP mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt has many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. The mcrypt-extension is deprecated will be removed in PHP 7.2. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution and are being maintained and is correct.

Comment: The key derivation is poor, use PBKDF2 or a similar key derivation method.

Comment: @ntoskrnl A CBC padding oracle attack only works if padding errors are returned to the attacker.

Answer (score 10):

For **PHP 7.1** and above, **mcrypt** function is deprecated. Here is the alternative using **openssl_encrypt**

```
$ciphertext = openssl_encrypt('string to be encrypted', 'DES-EDE3', 'key', OPENSSL_RAW_DATA);
$ciphertext = base64_encode($ciphertext);
```

You can use this online [Triple DES encryption](https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/triple-des-encrypt-decrypt) tool to cross check.

For other available cipher, you can invoke PHP method **openssl_get_cipher_methods()**

Answer (score 8):

This is the solution:

```
public function encrypt($data, $secret)
{
    //Generate a key from a hash
    $key = md5(utf8_encode($secret), true);

    //Take first 8 bytes of $key and append them to the end of $key.
    $key .= substr($key, 0, 8);

    //Pad for PKCS7
    $blockSize = mcrypt_get_block_size('tripledes', 'ecb');
    $len = strlen($data);
    $pad = $blockSize - ($len % $blockSize);
    $data .= str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);

    //Encrypt data
    $encData = mcrypt_encrypt('tripledes', $key, $data, 'ecb');

    return base64_encode($encData);
}

public function decrypt($data, $secret)
{
    //Generate a key from a hash
    $key = md5(utf8_encode($secret), true);

    //Take first 8 bytes of $key and append them to the end of $key.
    $key .= substr($key, 0, 8);

    $data = base64_decode($data);

    $data = mcrypt_decrypt('tripledes', $key, $data, 'ecb');

    $block = mcrypt_get_block_size('tripledes', 'ecb');
    $len = strlen($data);
    $pad = ord($data[$len-1]);

    return substr($data, 0, strlen($data) - $pad);
}
```

Regards.

Comment: Your decrypt function delivers an empty string! Please fix it.

Answer (score 6):

> https://github.com/iam-raihan96/3DES-ECB-Cryptography-in-PHP

here i wrote **3DES-ECB** Cryptography in **PHP**. there you will get two class file "**Crypt_mcrypt**" using "**mcrypt**" and "**Crypt_openssl**" using **"openssl"**. so you can use any of them but it is

> highly recomended to use "Crypt_openssl"

If you're typing the word mcrypt into your code, you're probably making a mistake. Although it's possible to provide a relatively secure cryptography library that builds on top of mcrypt (the earlier version of [defuse/php-encryption](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) did), switching your code to openssl will provide better security, performance, maintainability, and portability. Even better: use libsodium instead.

Comment: most precise result of 3des ✨

Answer (score 0):

Hey @black buddy the decrypt function is perfect the thing is that you need to pass the encyrpted data by the function encrypt.

```
<?php 
  $encryption_key = "CE51E06875F7D964";
  $data='tokenNo=test&securityCode=111' ;
  // the below will return the encoded data you need to put the value in the variable $asl.
  echo encrypt($data,$encryption_key);
  function encrypt($data, $secret)
  {
    //Generate a key from a hash
    $key = md5(utf8_encode($secret), true);

     //Take first 8 bytes of $key and append them to the end of $key.
    $key .= substr($key, 0, 8);
    //Pad for PKCS7
    $blockSize = mcrypt_get_block_size('tripledes', 'ecb');
    $len = strlen($data);
    $pad = $blockSize - ($len % $blockSize);
    $data .= str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);

    //Encrypt data
    $encData = mcrypt_encrypt('tripledes', $key, $data, 'ecb');

    return base64_encode($encData);
  }

  //the below is the encryption of $data = 'token.....' which there above 
  $asl = 'xcFEvIdLXc0LX+lk46iIFY09GF+FL+SWM0PTNw669VE=';
  // this echo will provide you the $data which is there in the begining
  echo decrypt($asl , $encryption_key);

  function decrypt($data, $secret)
  {
    //Generate a key from a hash
    $key = md5(utf8_encode($secret), true);

    //Take first 8 bytes of $key and append them to the end of $key.
    $key .= substr($key, 0, 8);

    $data = base64_decode($data);

    $data = mcrypt_decrypt('tripledes', $key, $data, 'ecb');

    $block = mcrypt_get_block_size('tripledes', 'ecb');
    $len = strlen($data);
    $pad = ord($data[$len-1]);

    return substr($data, 0, strlen($data) - $pad);
  }

?>
```