# Using Triple DES(3DES) with PHP 7.1

Tags: php, des, 3des, tripledes, php-7.1

I need a way to encrypt and decrypt with 3des. I'm currently using php 7.1

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22592919/triple-des-encryption-decryption-using-php) question, but mcrypt is [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php) as of php 7.1 and I can't find any other resource for this.

Comment: Why 3DES? It's generally not considered secure nowadays.

Comment: @duskwuff Intergrating with systems that require it

Answer (score 1):

Continue to the Comments section of the function's manual and you'll see the following:

> If you're writing code to encrypt/encrypt data in 2015, you should use
>   openssl_encrypt() and openssl_decrypt(). The underlying library
>   (libmcrypt) has been abandoned since 2007, and performs far worse than
>   OpenSSL (which leverages AES-NI on modern processors and is
>   cache-timing safe).
>   [[Link to the full comment]](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php#117667)

So, Consider using [`openssl_encrypt()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php) & openssl_decrypt() instead.
They are still being supported and better performing.